# Add values to an identity(1,1) column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE project.teacher 
(
    PROFESSOR_Codigo SMALLINT IDENTITY( 100, 1),
    birth            DATE NOT NULL,
    phone            VARCHAR(15)
);

CREATE TABLE project.student
(
    STUDENT_Codigo IDENTITY( 1, 1),
    birth          DATE NOT NULL,
    phone          VARCHAR(15)
);
```

When I add a student to the student table it will increment 1 from the number 1, and stay (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...)

In the teacher table I already have data entered, and start with a value of 100 in the identity column, but when I add 1, it gets identity 1, not 101

I've tried everything, `scope_identity()`, `@@identity`, but I couldn't! Does anyone have any ideas?

What I do to insert a row into the teacher table:

```
INSERT INTO project.student 
VALUES ('1998-05-08', '963597461');

INSERT INTO project.teacher
VALUES ('1994-05-09', '968413692');
```

Comment: "*I've tried everything, scope_identity (), @@ identitty*" - this makes me wonder what exactly you are doing to insert rows since they cannot help you set an identity value. Can you share the code that does the insert?

Comment: already updated

Comment: Why is this tagged c#?

Comment: because I'm calling wpf, but already removing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
dbcc checkident(teacher, noreseed)
```

this will return the current identity value of the ident column. your create statement is fine so maybe something went wrong on the on create?

Comment: give me that: 
"Checking identity information: current identity value '2', current column value '104'"

Comment: then thats your answer. the table was set to start with a seed of 100, but current seed is 2. to reset the seed use
dbcc checkident(teacher, reseed, 101)

Comment: the reseed value sets the value above which the next value will be given. with a reseed of 100, the first insert will give id 101. i dont know what you want to start at. from the check ident id say 104

Comment: ok, that's right, i deleted the table and created it again and it worked. thank you,
I put, from 105 that was the value that had given me